# Transparent pixels in filled area?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to fill an area selected by the magic wand, but I keep getting  pixels that are transparent. Below is an area that's supposed to be filled with red, but there are clearly many pixels that are transparent. Does anyone know why this is the case?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you selecting the area? Can't use simply use a brush and paint in the areas that are missing?

Comment: @Scott I'm just using the magic wand to select the area. I wonder why the opacity of the filled area isn't consistent.

Comment: Probably because the magic wand is seeing variations in color/hue/luminosity and the tolerance is set to *not* select variations outside a specific range. The magic wand will typically leave "holes" unless the area being clicked is a solid, flat, color.

Comment: @Scott The transparent areas aren't actually "holes". Those areas are fully selected by the wand. You can zoom in to see the holes, but there are fully selected areas that are filled with a <100% opacity.

Comment: They aren't fully selected.

Comment: @Scott How come? If you look at [this](https://i.imgur.com/LboyaSo.png), the yellow arrow points to a 'hole', but the blue arrow points to a fully selected area that's transparent. Also, the opacity varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand the confusion.

In Photoshop selections below 50% opacity will *not* show the "marching ants". It is entirely possible to have an area selected in part, but see no "marching ants". Simply because there  are no "marching ants" it doesn't mean there is no selection or that there is a *complete* selection.

Areas which are below 50% opacity *can be* part of an overall selection. However they are not *completely* selected - only a *percent* of the area is selected.

If you then "fill" the selection, only the *percent which is selected* is filled. The area *won't* be filled 100%.

[image]

This merely how the Magic Wand tool works. Sometimes you can increase the *Tolerance* of the Magic Wand tool in the **Control Bar** to select more areas. But there are times when that won't really help.

Using a selection method which is *not* based upon the *click* of color/luminosity is generally better, if that is an option. For well defined areas often the Polygonal Lasso or Pen Tool can work better. Even Quick Mask using a brush may create a better selection.

The Magic Wand tool, in my experience, is really only useful as a *starting point* which will need to be refined with a brush (Quick Mask/Layer Mask) or when the area being selected is a solid, flat color.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know the magic wand would only partially select an area. Is there a way to make the magic wand select 100% even the colour/luminosity is within the threshold? I'm actually just trying to paint a bounded area red, e.g., a road, what selection tool would you recommend if the Magic Wand behaves so unpredictably?

Comment: Hi @JohnM. if it were me, after the Magic Wand click, I'd switch to Quick Mask mode (Tap the Q key on the keyboard) and then use a brush to refine the selection. Tap Q again to leave Quick Mask Mode. Or.. use the Pen tool to draw a path around the area I want selected and then use the Path Panel to convert the path to a selection.

Comment: Hi @Scott. Thanks. Well, I was hoping for a solution with less manual selection. I thought the Magic Wand could pull it off. I wish there was a way to make the selection binary rather than being faithful to the original image's colour. That's a shame. :(

Comment: You can switch to quick mask and then use Levels or Curves to adjust the selection(mask).

Comment: Actually, I think I've found a better solution. If I set Magic Wand's Sample Size to 5 by 5 Average, the whole selection can be painted with a flat colour. Not sure why though.

Comment: That increases the tolerance essentially. Rather than selecting 1 value, it's selecting a range of values based upon the 3x3 average. basically, it just broadens the "range" of the selection.

Comment: Sorry, correction. It wasn't the 3x3 average that fixed it. It was disabling Anti-alias! :D